# Firebase authenticated user cannot write to database

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have the following Database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

on the iOS side:

```
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCustomToken(token, completion: { (user, error) in

        if error == nil {

            let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(user!.uid)

            userRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snap) in
                //....

                printD("working...")

                }, withCancelBlock: { (error) in
                    printD(error)
            })
        }
    })
}
```

console output:

```
[Error Domain=com.firebase Code=1 "Permission Denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Permission Denied}]
```

printing the user!.uid gives `"ODEzYjIzNzctMTFmMC00NjhhLWIxNTAtZjExN2I0MXXXXXX1"`

Comment: you've only defined rules for users/uid, what about the rest of the database? That could be stopping you.

Comment: I dont have anything else in the data base only users node @Wink

Comment: Is it somehow possible that your signInWithToken is not working.?

Comment: @Dravidian it is working i have an authenticated user

Comment: The code and rules look good to me at first glance. Just to humor us: can you add a print statement for `user!.uid` and show the value in the question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen take a look at the updated question